# Problem using eyeD3 to add cover art to mp3 files

Tags: mp3-tag, eyed3

I use the following command in a folder:

```
eyeD3 --add-image "coverfile_.jpg:FRONT_COVER" *mp3
```

This adds the cover art BUT if an mp3 file of the same name was previously referenced in ANOTHER folder the cover art for that previous file is used.

So, if, for example the folder I am processing is a "Best Of" CD I get a hodge bodge of covers rather than the cover for that CD, even though I specify it in the command..

Where is eyeD3 getting them from and can I "flush" them???

Comment: Does sound like a bug. But the full option is actually `--add-image IMG_PATH:TYPE[:DESCRIPTION]` so you should able to put the *full path* of your cover image to get around this issue. So something like: `eyeD3 --add-image "~/tmp/coverfile_.jpg:FRONT_COVER" *mp3`. Also I see this in the docs: 'All PATH arguments are parsed and displayed. Directory paths are searched recursively.'

Comment: I always have the jpg in the folder. The Folder is always at the bottom of the search tree. I tried: eyeD3 --add-image "./coverfile_.jpg:FRONT_COVER" *mp3    and get the same results.  eyeD3 seems to have built a database of covers somewhere.... but where?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the culprit is VLC which substitutes cover art from a previous .mp3 of the name name, rather than displaying the one actually on the .mp3 file

Comment: Where does VLC store cover art?